# What do these HP-UX PA-RISC aCC compiler options mean?

Tags: hp-ux, compiler-options, acc, pa-risc

I'm checking a 7 years old C/C++ system's Makefile. It was compiled by HP aCC, and it's running on HP-UX PA-RISC. I found many cflags descriptions here: http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/aCxx/Online_Help/options.htm , but these ones I didnt find anywhere:

+Z, +DA2.0, +DS2.0, +W.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

- +Z - Cause the compiler to generate position independent code (PIC) for use in building shared libraries.
- +DA2.0 -  To generate code for PA-RISC 2.0 for 32 bit or narrow mode
- +DSmodel - Use the instruction scheduler tuned to the model specified
- +Warg1[,arg2,...,argn] - Selectively suppresses any specified warning messages,where arg1 through argn are valid compiler warning message numbers